# Multiple Criteria Match (and Value between Range)

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, multiple-columns

I need to be able to return the class ??? based on a match based on course, category, gender, and age which would fall between the min and max acceptable.  I am thinking that this would be some form of index(match(......however I cannot figure out how to fit it with the range and ensuring the the other 3 requirements match.

Below is a link to a sample of what I am looking for.  Need ??? solution in M2

https://www.dropbox.com/s/t57vjywj8ps414m/Test%20Matching%20Based%20on%20Range.xlsx

Answer (score 0):

You can use this array formula:

```
=INDEX($G$2:$G$49;MATCH(1;(L2>=$D$2:$D$49)*(L2<=$E$2:$E$49)*(I2=$A$2:$A$49)*(J2=$B$2:$B$49)*(K2=$C$2:$C$49);0))
```

Dont forget to Ctrl Shift Enter to enter the formula (it is an array formula)

Depending on your regional settings you may need to replace field separator ";" by ","